# Laravel templates

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу выводить меню в блоге, построенном на *laravel* динамически. Если из админки добавилась категория, она должна появится в меню. Иными словами, мне нужно в основной *template* передать массив категорий.

Так как в *laravel* передача переменных происходит в контроллере, выходит что нужно каждый раз при вызове шаблона передавать ему массив. Каким образом лучше всего передавать массив категорий в шапку шаблона?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы пробросить данные из контроллера в представление существует несколько способов.

**Первый:** Сформировать данные до оператора `return` и воспользоваться функцией `compact()`. В виде аргументов она принимает названия масивов и переменных без `$`. По этим же именам но с `$` они доступны в представлении. Плюс такого подхода можно передать сколько угодно переменных и массивов, а также обектов классов.

```
public function someFunction()
{
    // каким то образом получаем наш масив данных
    $customArray = ['foo'=>'baar'];
    // передаем его в представление
    return view('customView', compact('customArray'));
}
```

**Второй:** Сформировать данные непосредственно в операторе `return` передав вторым параметром функции `view()` нужный нам масив. В представлении масив доступен как $data

```
public function someFunction()
{
    $data = ['foo'=>'baar'];
    return view('customView', $data);
}
```

**Третий** (вариант похожий напредыдущий, но там формировался асоциативный масив, а тут пары: переменная - значение(в которое можно запихнуть и массив))

```
public function someFunction()
{
    $data = ['foo'=>'baar'];
    return view('customView')->with('customArray', $data);
}
```

Comment: Извините, я плохо сформулировал вопрос. Вопрос именно в том, как передать массив в одном месте, в одной точке, а не каждый раз при вызове шаблона

Comment: попробуйте `view()->share('key', 'value');`

Comment: посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, использовал ваш способ в главном контроллере)